# Error in charToDate(x) and Error in as.POSIXlt.character

Tags: r

I have a big data set with data that spans over a year. Different people need different 'time-subsets' of this data but all with the same kind of plots.

Instead of putting the 'timesubsetting' each time into each plot, I would like to define the timespan in kind of a 'parameter' with which the plots then work.

In trying to do this, I get error in charToDate(x) / Error in as.POSIXlt.character or wrong results.

Here a (hopefully) reproducable Example. I have to admit that I'm a bloody beginner with R … and programming.

I hope, someone can help me. Thanks.

```
# R Version 4.0.3
# Windows 10
# RStudio 1.4.1103

library(plotly) # in this example only for the pipe %>% working, in real for plots

# build data frame example
Name <- c("Müller", "Meiern", "Hugentobler", "Muster", "Klein", "Gross", "Basler")
Day <- as.Date(c("2020-02-18", "2020-02-19", "2020-02-20", "2020-02-18","2020-02-21", "2020-02-22", "2020-02-23"))
DatFra <- data.frame(Name, Day)


try <- DatFra %>%
  subset(Day == "2020-02-18") # Works as expectet, but this method does not achieve my goal  


# with format Data
PerStart_dt <- as.Date("2020-02-18")

try <- DatFra %>%
  subset(Day == "PerStart_dt") # gives Error 1 (look at the end of the code)

try <- DatFra %>%
  subset(Day == as.Date("PerStart_dt")) # gives Error 1

try <- DatFra %>%
  subset(Day == as.Date("PerStart_dt", format = "%Y-%m-%d")) # no Error but result with 0 observation in try


# with format character
PerStart_cr <- "2020-02-18"

try <- DatFra %>%
  subset(Day == "PerStart_cr") # gives Error 1

try <- DatFra %>%
  subset(Day == as.Date("PerStart_cr")) # gives Error 1

try <- DatFra %>%
  subset(Day == as.Date("PerStart_cr", format = "%Y-%m-%d")) # no Error but result with 0 observation in try


# with format Posixct

Day <- as.POSIXct(c("2020-02-18", "2020-02-19", "2020-02-20", "2020-02-18","2020-02-21", "2020-02-22", "2020-02-23"))
DatFra <- data.frame(Name, Day)

PerStart_PXct <- as.POSIXct("2020-02-18", format = "%Y-%m-%d")

try <- DatFra %>%
  subset(Day == "PerStart_PXct") # gives Error 2

try <- DatFra %>%
  subset(Day == as.POSIXct("PerStart_PXct")) # gives Error 2

try <- DatFra %>%
  subset(Day == as.POSIXct("PerStart_PXct", format = "%Y-%m-%d")) # no Error but result with 0 observation in try


# Error 1:
# Error in charToDate(x) : 
#   character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

# Error 2:
# Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
#   character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure. But I think it is simply. Instead of using `"PerStart_dt"` you should use `PerStart_dt`. This is your object you assigned the date to.

```
# RStudio 1.4.1103

library(plotly) # in this example only for the pipe %>% working, in real for plots

# build data frame example
Name <- c("Müller", "Meiern", "Hugentobler", "Muster", "Klein", "Gross", "Basler")
Day <- as.Date(c("2020-02-18", "2020-02-19", "2020-02-20", "2020-02-18","2020-02-21", "2020-02-22", "2020-02-23"))
DatFra <- data.frame(Name, Day)


try <- DatFra %>%
  subset(Day == "2020-02-18") # Works as expectet, but this method does not achieve my goal  


# with format Data
PerStart_dt <- as.Date("2020-02-18")

try1 <- DatFra %>%
  subset(Day == PerStart_dt) # gives no Error

try2 <- DatFra %>%
  subset(Day == as.Date(PerStart_dt)) # gives no Error 

try3 <- DatFra %>%
  subset(Day == as.Date(PerStart_dt, format = "%Y-%m-%d")) # no Error and result with 2 observation in try
```

Comment: Thanks TarJae !!!
I feel ashamed not having seen that on my own.

On the other hand I'm happy, that the solution is so easy.

In three month I'm going into retirement. Then I will have time to go deeper into R, programming and therefore hopefully get a better understanding on how things work.

Best wishes to Austria from Switzerland.

Comment: Done the accepting. Regarding voting up however I get this message: 
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."